# Can I pass an intent within RecyclerViewAdapter coming from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[LayoutDiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU8KJ.jpg)

This is not an issue on mobile because I can use `startActivity(intent)` with the intent holding my data and the Activity I want to open, but in a 2 pane UI, I'm having an issue where I have a grid layout set up in **Fragment A**, and the onClick for my GridView is being set in the **RecyclerView.Adapter**.

Adapter is setting `onClickListeners` for **Fragment A** but I want data to be passed to **Fragment B** and then have `Fragment B` refresh, rather than start a new Activity so on a 2 pane UI, it refreshes that part of the app. How can I do that within my RecyclerViewAdapter? I've made a diagram portraying my issue as best as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onclicklistener:
Remove fragmentB, pass values to a new FragmentB using setArguments and then reattach FragmentB.

I am not sure from your question about whether the onClickListener in fragment A is passing data to B or whether the adapter should pass data